# Hours for אהבה רבה on Shavuos; true or exaggeration?

Tags: tefilla, time, shavuos, bircas-krias-shema

In two recent shiurim I  heard a story about a certain *(don't remember the name)* Yeshiva in pre-war Europe where they took (three?) hours to say אהבה רבה (the blessing before Shema) on the morning of Shovuos.

Is there any truth in this and if yes, how did it fit in with the available time for davenning Shacharis?

I searched online using a number of search terms in English and Hebrew with no success.

Comment: am guessing would not be a valid bracha.

Comment: @Loewian why? there's no upper limit to how slow you can say something assuming you aren't completely paused.

Comment: @mevaqesh I did Google it - with a number of search terms in English and Hebrew and no joy!

Comment: Consider mentioning what you did, so each user doesn't replicate your and their efforts.

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you sure there's no upper limit? How would you define a pause? Is it even physically possible to say ~35 words/hr - ~2 minutes/word without pausing? In any case, even if one were halachically yotzei, it sounds phenomenally bdieved and inappropriate: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA RAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..."

Comment: @loewian there are halakhot about shoheh kedei ligmor kulah. Basically you can pause between every word the amount of time it takes to say the whole paragraph. If we add in piyutim as was common in many places, that's easily a whole day. As far as being appropriate that would really depend on context

Comment: @DoubleAA well the OP should have mentioned if they were being mafsik the nusach habracha that chazal were metaken with 3 hours of piyutim;)

Comment: @loew I don't see any reason for him to mention that or to assume he meant there were piyutim (or that they are a hefesk or that chazal were metaken the whole nusach of that brakha). I just meant kol shekein if there were piyutim then three hours is easy to get.

Comment: @DoubleAA (In any case, even at a slow 100 wpm, kdei ligmor kula is about a minute meaning an hour forty or so is the max without piyutim.) http://www.speechinminutes.com/

Comment: If a person spends 3 hours (10800 seconds) saying Ahavah Rabbah (103 words in Nusach Ashkenaz), that's an average of ~105 seconds per word - just shy of two minutes just to say "ahavah." Even allotting for a toch kdei dibbur between words, that's an awfully long time. Nusach Sefard's 142-word Ahavas Olam is slightly more plausible: 76 seconds per word, or just over a minute. Edut HaMizrach and Nusach Ari, at 140 words each, come out about the same. Throw in piyutim and you *might* be able to get it under the minute per word mark.

Comment: @DonielF Shema is lechatchila before Hanetz and bedieved after. It's Shmoneh Esrei which is bedieved before Hanetz and lechatchila after. Hence the practice of Vatikin with Shema before and Shemoneh Esrei after.